# Kotlin multiplatform, iOS/Android. Использование платформенных типов в актуальных реализациях

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

**Теоретическая часть вопроса.**

У меня есть общий data-класс со свойством, реализация класса которого зависит от платформы

```
class Accident(
    ...
    val location: AccidentLocation
)

expect class AccidentLocation {
    fun distanceTo(point: AccidentLocation): Double
}
```

У android'a и у iOS'а свой подход к работе с местоположением и было бы логично использовать нативные классы/методы для реализации актуальных классов.

Например для android'a

```
actual class AccidentLocation(val location: Location, val address: String) {
    actual fun distanceTo(point: AccidentLocation): Double {
        return location.distanceTo(point.location)
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** я правильно понимаю принцип мультиплатформенности от Kotlin?

**Практическая часть вопроса.**

Я никак не могу добиться того, чтобы в android-части мультиплатформенного модуля были видны необходимые библиотеки.

`gradle.build` для общего кода (по сути копипаста из руководства)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos")  \
                               ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }

        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
            api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

Студия в упор не видит содержимого `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0` и, соответственно, импортировать `Location` никак не получается.

**Вопрос:** Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Этот класс, нормально себе импортируется.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location

И вот этот из `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` тоже

> com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient

Не то или не там ищете, похоже.

Comment: Вы уверены, что поняли вопрос? Речь про общий модуль kotlin multiplatform проекта. В обычной то жизни ясен хрен, что все нормально импортируется.

Comment: Я скачал `kotlin-mpp-example` с GitHub, добавил ваши зависимости в модуль `greeting` и там же в `androidLibMain` все отлично импортируется.

Comment: ок, спасибо за наводку, буду изучать. Туториал с офф-сайта несколько по иначе описывает весь процесс. (могли бы ссылку дать, кстати, вдруг кому понадобится https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-mpp-example)

Comment: Kotlin multiplatform в активной разработке, это все еще в статусе "эксперимент", может меняться и перерабатываться. Лучше верить тому, что свежее.